# 2D Array in C++ -

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to complete my homework involving c++. I'm using Dev C++ to build this.I've tried my best to do this.

These are the requirements that are required to be fulfilled:

1. Build a 2D Array that will record assignment marks & examination marks
2. Input assignment marks & examination marks
3. Calculate average assignment marks and examination marks
4. Calculate the total assignment mark & examination mark
5. Output all the calculated marks

It returns this error:

> [Error] invalid operands of types 'int [2][10]'and 'int'to binary operator & [Error] invalid operands of types 'int [3][10]'and 'int'to binary operator.

Here's the code that I've come up with:

```
main()
{
int assignment_marks [2] [10];
int examination_marks [3] [10];

float average_marks;
int total_marks;
int num;
int i;

printf ("input assignment marks:");
for (i=0; i<=10; i++)
scanf ("%d" , &assignment_marks [i] );

printf ("input examination marks:");
for (i=0; i<=20; i++)
scanf ("%d" , &examination_marks [i] );

printf ("calculate average assignment marks :");
scanf ("%d" , &average_marks);
average_marks = assignment_marks / 10;

printf ("calculate average examination marks :");
scanf ("%d" , &average_marks);
average_marks = examination_marks / 10;

for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++)

{

printf ("calculate total assignment marks :");
scanf ("%d" , &total_marks);
total_marks = assignment_marks / 100*100 ;
printf ("calculate total examination marks :");
scanf ("%d" , &total_marks);
total_marks = examination_marks / 100*100 ;


}


}
```

Comment: Is this code a function? Which line(s) give the error?

Comment: You can't divide an array by a number. You should review the chapter on arrays in your favourite C++ book, starting with one dimension.

Comment: The instructions say "Build **a** 2D Array that will record assignment marks & examination marks" (emphasis mine). You have two 2D arrays, one with two ten-element arrays and one with three. Where did you get the `2` and `3` from?

Comment: on which line is the error? what is not clear about the error message?

Comment: These lines are returning the error message :-

average_marks = assignment_marks / 10;
average_marks = examination_marks / 10;
total_marks = assignment_marks / 100*100 ;
total_marks = examination_marks / 100*100 ;

Comment: Just so you know: if they are teaching you `printf`, `scanf` and C style arrays like this in a *C++* course, the course is about two decades out of date with modern best practices.

Comment: Your code is C89. Your code is not valid C++.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, what you are trying to do is, you are trying to divide the whole array by 10. Here is the example:
We have an array

```
1
2
3
4
```

as values and all of this is stored into our variable `array`.

If we want to accumulate the values in the whole array, we do the following:

- We create a temporary variable
- We use it to save the current value of the **array element**
- And we move onto the next element

Alright, now let's see how this will work in code:

```
int sum(0);

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
   sum = sum + array[i];
```

What's happening here and what are all these variables? We create a for loop to iterate over the array's elements one by one. We get each element's value and we sum it up into our variable `sum`.

- `i` serves as iterator to get each element
- `sum` serves as accumulator to summarize all the elements
- `array` is our array
- `i < 4` is because we have a total of 4 elements, `0 to 3` as indexes.

If you want to divide, you can apply the same method, but divide after the summary. Let me give you real quick example with your exercise:

We have an array with exam scores. For example `double scores[] = { 5.5, 3.4, 4.5, 5.7 };` and we want to get the average score for the student. Notice, that we have **4 exams**.

```
double scores[] = {
   5.5,
   3.4,
   4.5,
   5.7
};

double sum = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
   sum += scores[i];

double average = (sum / 4);
```

As you see, the same logic, we iterate over each element of our array, accumulate into certain variable and then the addition here is, that we divide by the number of exams we have in order to find the average score we got.